# Should unrecoverable exceptions from HTTP parameter problems be caught?

Tags: django, web-services, http, exception, django-views

Is it necessary to catch errors stemming from HTTP inputs? Is it ever a good idea to let it fail naturally (allow the exception to bubble up)?

I have a Django view for a server side interface for an AJAX call that looks something like this:

```py
def some_view(request):
    try:
        some_int = int(request.POST.get('some_int')) # May raise ValueError or TypeError
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('some_int must be an int')
    # ... Code that assumes some_int is an int
    return HttpResponse('The normal response')
```

Is it ever acceptable in production code to have something like this?

```py
def some_view(request):
    some_int = int(request.POST.get('some_int')) # Ignore ValueError or TypeError raised
    # ... Code that assumes some_int is an int
    return HttpResponse('normal_response')
```

As I accept more parameters, I find that it is frustrating to maintain so many try/except blocks which are mostly the same and I end up with a ton of boiler plate code.

Of course I tried to refactor this into a separate function but since Django requires an `HttpResponse` to be returned, not raised as an exception, I can't plug it into a view without a try/except block. Also, conversions to int aren't the only thing I check... there are a lot of business logic sanity checks performed depending on the input as well. For example, I would validate that the JSON passed is of a specific format (i.e. array of objects of int array, etc.).

My views end up being 70+ lines of code just for sanity checks and a few lines of code that actually generate the response. Somehow I feel like there should be a more elegant way but I haven't found one so I'm considering forgoing all checks and just letting Django take care of it. **Is this a bad idea?**

I'm aware of the following potential problems if I don't catch the exceptions:

1. The same HTTP 500 is returned for all errors
2. If logging is enabled in production, it would probably log an error every time an invalid input occurs

Are there other problems I should be aware of? It just feels wrong not to catch exceptions from user inputs even though there's not much I can do about it in terms of recovery logic.

Comment: At your server side , you can put only one `try except` block . and return something like `server error` . And you can validate int field at client side using javascript .

Comment: Yes I was considering putting a single try/except block in each view, then having a function to validate each type of input. In the end it seemed like overkill and I sometimes have slightly different validation logic for each view even with the same type of input. Also, I don't want to rely on JS validation checks as it can be tampered with. Just fed up with validations.. I don't see any shortcuts short of writing my own framework or forgoing validations :(

Comment: you can use django forms for server side validation .

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, thanks. However it doesn't parse JSON though, which is mainly what I'm having my gripe with...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this is by writing your own [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) that catches the exceptions and turns them into your desired response.

That might look something like this:

```
# views.py
def some_view(request): 
    some_int = int(request.POST.get('some_int'))
    # ... Code that assumes some_int is an int
    return HttpResponse('normal_response')


# middleware.py
class MyValidationMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, e):
        if isinstance(e, ValueError):
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('Input did not validate')
        else:
            return None  # let it bubble up
```

(Since middleware is site-wide, you might want to explicitly define your own input-validation exceptions to distinguish them from other sorts of exceptions that might occur.)

Alternatively, you could do the same sort of thing with per-view decorators.